# Nginx - Regla para un archivo + regla para un php

Tags: linux, servidor, nginx, debian

Tengo un proyecto que si la uri es http://test.local , deseo construir http://test.local/promociones/ que esto mediante una expresión es lo equivalente a http://test.local/index.php?modulo=promociones

El problema lo tengo que he puesto una carpeta en el directorio del proyecto que se llama "promociones" y dentro cuelga una carpeta que es "docs" con un archivo "bases-legales.pdf"

Con lo que al final tendré estas 2 posibles urls
http://test.local/promociones/ <== esta debe cargar el contenido de un archivo php
http://test.local/promociones/docs/bases-legales.pdf que debe descargar el archivo php

El contenido de mi configuración en nginx es este

```
# nginx configuration by winginx.com

location = /promociones{
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?modulo=promociones;
}

location / {
 rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?mod=$1;
 rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /index.php?mod=$1;
```

}

El problema lo tengo al intentar acceder a http://test.local/promociones que me devuelve un **403 Forbidden**

Gracias,

Comment: en tu codigo de nginx haces referencia a `/promocoes` en lugar de `/promociones`, revisa eso

Comment: fué un error al escribir , corregido